# Issues in extracting first and last string from rows of texts which are separated by '>' in a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr, substring

I have a dataframe which looks like that:

```
 DF$Lst 
 [1] "Some text > in > a string"
     "Another > text in > another > set of string"  
     "This is only > One text"
     "NA"
     ..... so forth
```

If you had noticed that, each row has a text which is separated by `'>'`

I want to create 'TWO' new columns which should have the first string and last string only, for example:

```
  Text                                         Col1         Col2
  Some text > in > a string                    Some text    a string
  Another > text in > another > set of string  Another      set of string
```

I was trying with a function:

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

substrRight(x, 6)
```

But I think this is not the right approach. Because the above function is not helping. Can we have a better one to solve the issues?

Comment: You can do `t(sapply(strsplit(str1, " > "), function(x) c(x[1], x[length(x)])))`

Comment: thanks once again, please let me try that. I will revert asap.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
 extract(Text, into = c('Col1', 'Col2'), '^([^>]+) >.* > ([^>]+)$', 
       remove = FALSE)
#                                       Text      Col1          Col2
#1                   Some text > in > a string Some text      a string
#2 Another > text in > another > set of string   Another set of string
```

---

Or with `base R`, `split` at the `>` and then get the first and last element

```
DF[c('Col1', 'Col2')] <- t(sapply(strsplit(DF$Text, " > "),
             function(x) c(x[1], x[length(x)])))
```

#### Update

In the updated dataset 'DF3', the `NAs` are character strings.  We can convert it to real NAs

```
is.na(DF3$Text) <- DF3$Text == "NA"
DF3[c('Col1', 'Col2')] <- t(sapply(strsplit(DF3$Text, " > "),
       function(x) c(x[1], x[length(x)])))
DF3
#                                         Text      Col1          Col2
#1                   Some text > in > a string Some text      a string
#2 Another > text in > another > set of string   Another set of string
#3                               This > is one      This        is one
#4                                        <NA>      <NA>          <NA>
```

Or similar to @Onyambu's pattern

```
 DF3 %>%
   extract(Text, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), 
               "^([^>]*)>(?:.*>)?([^>]*)$", remove = FALSE)
 #                                       Text       Col1           Col2
 #1                   Some text > in > a string Some text        a string
 #2 Another > text in > another > set of string   Another   set of string
 #3                               This > is one      This          is one
 #4                                        <NA>       <NA>           <NA>
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(Text = c("Some text > in > a string", 
 "Another > text in > another > set of string"
)), .Names = "Text", row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")   



DF3 <- structure(list(Text = c("Some text > in > a string",
"Another > text in > another > set of string", "This > is one", "NA")), 
 .Names = "Text", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks akrun but i got the error `Error in UseMethod("extract_") : 
  no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"` .. is it because of the reason that there are some `'NAs'` in some rows??

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque  No, it is because your dataset is a `matrix`.  I assume it is a `data.frame`.  Convert to `data.frame with `as.data.frame(DF)` and it should work

Comment: it is dataframe I just checked. and also updated the issue with some more clarity on the data it looks like.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I learned a lot.. I was wondering, if `DF$Lst` col has any rows that have `NAs` or only one `>` e.g. `This is text > with one LT` kind of data in any rows, will I still be able to split the row into cols with either NA, NA or before and after '>' strings into these cols?

Comment: It is not clear to me.  This is based on the example you provided

Comment: ok. let's try this one... we want NA's in two columns (and that was my doubt, if it will happen or not while applying your suggestions). `DF3 <- structure(list(Text = c("Some text > in > a string", 
                              "Another > text in > another > set of string", "This > is one", "NA")), .Names = "Text", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque  The NA that you showed are not real NAs.  These are characters strings.

Answer (score 2):

Base R version:

```
text=DF$Lst# Will assume this is given
read.table(text=sub(">.*>",">",text),sep=">")
          V1             V2
1 Some text        a string
2   Another   set of string


cbind(text,read.table(text=sub(">.*>",">",text),sep=">"))
                                         text         V1             V2
1                   Some text > in > a string Some text        a string
2 Another > text in > another > set of string   Another   set of string
```

Another base R approach:

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,regmatches(text,regexec("(.*)>.*>(.*)",text))))
                                           X1                 X2             X3
1                   Some text > in > a string         Some text        a string
2 Another > text in > another > set of string Another > text in   set of string
```

## EDIT:

```
read.table(text=sub("(^.*?)>(?:.*>)*(.*$)","\\1>\\2",text),sep=">",fill = T,na.strings = "")
             V1             V2
1    Some text        a string
2      Another   set of string
3 This is only        One text
4            NA           <NA>
```

or you can do:

```
read.table(text=sub("(^[^>]*).*?([^>]*$)","\\1>\\2",text),sep=">",fill = T,na.strings = "")
             V1             V2
1    Some text        a string
2      Another   set of string
3 This is only        One text
4          <NA>             NA
```

Using `separate`

```
 separate(data.frame(text),text,c("col1","col2"),"((?:>.*)>|>)",fill="right" )
           col1           col2
1    Some text        a string
2      Another   set of string
3 This is only        One text
4            NA           <NA>
```

Comment: thanks but one check, if the DF$Lst also has some `'NA'` in it? will it work?

Comment: What do you mean with NA?? can you give an example?

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque   so in the NA, how do you want it to return? Also in the one with just a single > the third text, how do you want it to return?

Comment: I think the best idea is, cols should be filled with NAs or kept empty for the rows where DF$Lst is NA, right?

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque What of the place with just one `>`??

Comment: thanks. I think with just one `'>'` we can split the before and after text into col1 and col2.

Comment: in your approach.. `separate(data.frame(text).... ` i got an `Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not an integer vector`

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque Oh you have to give it a name: ie `separate(data.frame(text=text)…)` or if you are using the `DF$list` you should do,`separate(DF,Lst,c("col1","col2"),"((?:>.*)>|>)",fill="right" )`